# Timing of finality of a transaction in Mainnet

Tags: transaction

Hello i am facing some troubles when moving from test-net to main-net, my transactions seems to have to wait a long time for being reflected in the explorer, also i can not do any more transactions until they appear in the explorer, yesterday I had to wait almost 10 minutes. Now I am waiting for more than half an hour! and i can not see my transaction in the explorer neither do any other transaction.

Everything works fine in test-net but on main-net things gets complicated, I have noticed that Nami Wallet and Yoroi work terrific, but sending my transactions from Blockfrost endpoint may be the thing that makes things slow,  Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Just be patient. This behavior is because these days the blockchain has been really saturated, 90-95%.

Additionally, today was the launch of [Sundaeswap](https://sundaeswap.finance/), that means, more saturation.

This also has an impact in the wallets, you can try [CCVault](https://ccvault.io/app/mainnet/welcome)

Your transactions can take 10 minutes or even more when the blockchain is saturated.

Comment: Yesterday i waited more than an hour..  went to sleep and only in the morning i could see my transaction today i sent one transaction 3 hours ago... i have the hash 95653ab27d3467908945e21e09efc7d90bff72854f09b9ad969db03a17f8fa37 but.. now 3 hours later i can not see it in the explorer.

Comment: Yes, that's the reason this year Cardano will scale: https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2022/01/14/how-we-re-scaling-cardano-in-2022/

Comment: i have waited 9 hours! today :(

Comment: That's too much, I minted an NFT three hours ago, it took like 10 minutes. Try another wallet, CCVault seems to be performing better these days.

Comment: I was using blockfronst SendTx Endpoint no browser wallet

Comment: now i am getting this error: BlockfrostServerError: Mempool is full, please try resubmitting again later.
  but the first was submited so it is not related to blockfrost only but to thw whole blockchain.

Comment: Here is a nice tweet with an explanation from Alessadro: https://twitter.com/berry_ales/status/1485198340698562563?t=C3pw53AusKAEcitlLfnpbg&s=09

Answer (score 1):

The blocks are much more saturated on mainnet. It's normal to wait 5-10 minutes for a transaction to get into the block chain when the blocks are saturated.

Comment: Yesterday i waited more than an hour..  went to sleep and only in the morning i could see my transaction today i sent one transaction 3 hours age... i have the hash 95653ab27d3467908945e21e09efc7d90bff72854f09b9ad969db03a17f8fa37 but.. now 3 hours later i can not see it in the explorer.

Comment: Some wallets are better than others with dealing with the backlog.